# Jquery-maskMoney получить value

Tags: html, jquery, vue.js

Использую [эту](http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/) библиотеку для маски ввода

есть input

```
<input class="form-control" id="sum" v-on:click="inputValueFilterSum">
```

функция inputValueFilterSum

```
inputValueFilterSum: function(){
    var num = $('#sum').maskMoney()
},
```

И есть локальная переменная sum.

Нужно по окончанию ввода в input задать значения в sum из input.
Не могу разобраться как это сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать вот так :

```
 inputValueFilterSum: function () {
     var num = $("#sum").maskMoney()
     this.sum = num;
 }
```

Тогда переменная sum будет иметь значение num. Позже, её можно использовать где-то в другом коде блока :

```
<div>SUM : {{sum}}</div>
```